# Importing bootstrap less in webpack

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, webpack

I have followed examples from many different sources (including the less-loader usage examples) but I'm still having troubles importing bootstrap less code in a way I can customize it's variables elegantly.

Here is my webpack config:

webpackconfig.js

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./app/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "./dist/bundle.js",
    path: __dirname
  },
 module: {
  rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader/url" },
          { loader: "file-loader" }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-loader" },
          { loader: "less-loader" }
        ]
      },
      { 
        test: /\.png$/, 
        use: [ { loader: "url-loader?limit=100000" } ]
      },
      { 
        test: /\.jpg$/, 
        use: [ { loader: "file-loader" } ] 
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, 
        use: [ { loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" } ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, 
        use: [ { loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" } ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, 
        use: [ { loader: "file" } ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, 
        use: [ { loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" } ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: [ { loader: "babel-loader" } ],
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/        
      }
    ]
},

node: {
  console: true,
  fs: "empty",
  net: "empty",
  tls: "empty"
}

};
```

Now in order to do the importing, I have tried two different approaches. By importing the bootstrap less directly like:

```
import "bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less"
```

or by importing only my own less and then importing the bootstrap style in there like:

```
@import '~bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less';
```

In any case, here is my index.js:

index.js

```
import _ from 'lodash'
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'
import styles from  './style/style.less'


const app = document.getElementById("app")

ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    app
)
```

In either approach, I get the following error:

```
Error: Module 'D:\code\ox\node_modules\url\url.js' is not a loader (must have normal or pitch function)
    at loadLoader
```

I should mention that I can import my own style.less just fine...

Anyways, the repository for this code is real small and simple and is available [here](https://github.com/Hookkid/oX).

I know this turned out to be quite a read... appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems you need a url-loader as well

Comment: @VivekN Hi! I have "url-loader": "^0.5.9" installed currently. Is there any additional steps I should take?

Comment: Can I see your package.json as well

Comment: https://github.com/Hookkid/oX/blob/master/package.json

Comment: When do you get that error?

Comment: I cloned your repo and tried to run it.It's working fine for me.The webpack build succeeded.

Comment: when i >webpack my project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146884/discussion-between-hookkid-and-vivekn).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to your problem is using -loader prefix in all the loader's that you use.

The updated webpack.config.js should be as follows:-

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./app/index.js",
    output: {
        filename: "./dist/bundle.js",
        path: __dirname
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                { loader: "style-loader" },
                { loader: "file-loader" }
            ]
        }, {
            test: /\.less$/,
            use: [
                { loader: "style-loader" },
                { loader: "css-loader" },
                { loader: "less-loader" }
            ]
        }, {
            test: /\.png$/,
            use: [ { loader: "url-loader?limit=100000" } ]
        }, {
            test: /\.jpg$/,
            use: [ { loader: "file-loader" } ]
        }, {
            test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            use: [ { loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" } ]
        }, {
            test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            use: [ { loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" } ]
        }, {
            test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            use: [ { loader: "file-loader" } ]
        }, {
            test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            use: [ { loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" } ]
        }, {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            use: [ { loader: "babel-loader" } ],
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
        }]
    },
    node: {
        console: true,
        fs: "empty",
        net: "empty",
        tls: "empty"
    }
};
```

I hope this solves your issue... :)

Comment: Yep! That indeed solved the problem - thank you!

I will now do some reading to try to understand why that is.

Thanks again!